# Remove combinde duplicates in datagridview vb.net. net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, duplicates

Using vb.net how do I remove duplicates based on two cell values found in the same row? I know howhat to do this per column just not in sets of columns.

What I'm thinking is

```
    For LoopA As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
        For LoopB As Integer = LoopA + 1 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
            If DataGridView1.Rows(LoopA).Cells(2).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(LoopB).Cells(2).Value & DataGridView1.Rows(LoopA).Cells(3).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(LoopB).Cells(3).Value Then
                DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(LoopB)
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

I'm not intrested in the last column which are clients.  The first column is the product type and the second is the products phisical length.

The HD 300 seriers is what I want to have appear only once, since this is the only non unique combination that occurs.

How do I achieve this?
[image]

Comment: If this information comes from an SQL query, you can get rid easily of the duplicates by getting rid of the last column (the one you said you didn't cared about) and adding the keyword `DISTINCT` in your query.

Comment: Never mind...  I ment  to imply ignore the last column.... ta anyway :)

Comment: Please always post code formatted as code.

Comment: An ampersand (&) in vb.net is the string concatenation operator. You must use And to add another condition to your If statement.

Comment: Ok then, assuming that 1 and 2 are to be considered as duplicate, how do you deal with the Client column? As you cannot discriminate automatically, would you just drop it from the results table?

Comment: The client column could be removed before removing duplicates 1 and 2, that would be easy.

Comment: I also tried  the following but with no success either... 
`DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False

For Each Phase1 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                Dim ValCell1 As String = (Phase1.Cells(1).Value)
                Dim ValCell2 As String = (Phase1.Cells(2).Value)
   For Each Phase2 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If ((Phase2.Cells(1).Value) = ValCell1) And ((Phase2.Cells(2).Value) = ValCell2) Then
     DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(Phase2)
    End If
   Next
Next

DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = True`

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't need the last column, the best solution would be, as I pointed earlier, to change the query so you can use the `DISTINCT` keyword. It wouldn't work with the Client column, though, as this column wouldn't be amalgamated.

There is another method, much less elegant I think, but efficient nonetheless. You can create a new DataTable, populate it with no duplicate, and substitute it to the DataSource of your DataGridView.

```
    Dim originTable as DataTable = yourDataGridView.DataSource
    Dim destinationTable As New DataTable
    destinationTable.Columns.Add("Type", GetType(String))
    destinationTable.Columns.Add("Length", GetType(Integer))

    For Each row As DataRow In originTable.Rows
        Dim duplicates() As DataRow = destinationTable.Select("Type = " & row("Type").ToString & " AND Length = " & row("Length").ToString)
        If duplicates.Length = 0 Then
            destinationTable.Rows.Add(row("Type").ToString, row("Length"))
        End If
    Next

    yourDataGridView.DataSource = destinationTable
```

I couldn't test it in a rush so please consider it more as a suggestion which might require some tweaking than a solution as is. Hope it helps!